# Add a custom role to a resource group via powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to add a custom role via PowerShell script as follows:

```
    Write-Host "Assigning service principal to resource groups..."
    $resourceGroupTypes = "compute", "data", "prereqs"
    foreach ($resourceGroupType in $resourceGroupTypes)
    {
        $resourceGroupName = "$solutionAbbreviation-$resourceGroupType-$environmentAbbreviation"
        New-AzRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName "CSEO DevOps Role" -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ObjectId $servicePrincipal.Id
    }
```

On running this, I see the following error:

```
Visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2181475 for any permission issues.
New-AzRoleAssignment : Cannot find role definition with name 'CSEO DevOps Role'

+         New-AzRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName "CSEO DevOps Role" - ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzRoleAssignment], KeyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.NewAzureRoleAssignmentCommand
```

What am I missing? How do I add a custom role?

UPDATE:

I updated the script to:

```
$FullFileName = $scriptsDirectory + "\Scripts\role.json'"
New-AzRoleDefinition -InputFile $FullFileName
```

I see the error:

New-AzRoleDefinition : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: What the error message is telling you to do: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azroledefinition?view=azps-7.1.0#:~:text=%5B%5D-,Description,file%20or%20a%20PSRoleDefinition%20object.&text=Use%20Get%2DAzProviderOperation%20to%20get,be%20secured%20using%20Azure%20RBAC.

Comment: Thank you! Can I add ResourceGroup & ObjectId when using New-AzRoleDefinition?